# msg.sender and msg.value - do they work only for sent Etherum or do they work for ERC20 tokens sent to the contract too?

Tags: solidity, vyper, msg.sender

I'm starting to learn Vyper and I wanted to ask a question regarding msg.sender and msg.value

If I created a simple contract that simply returns msg.sender and msg.value I understand that if I sent ETH to this contract, the emmited event will correctly give me the sender's address and the amount of ETH sent.

My question is - if I sent an ERC20 token to this contract, would it behave in the same way?

(and please excuse any mistakes below in the contract code, treat it as pseudocode as I'm still learning :-))

```
event Transfer:
    sender: indexed(address)
    value: uint256

@payable
@external
def talk()
    log.Transfer(msg.sender,msg.value)
```

Comment: msg.sender is who called the function and msg.value is only for the native token in the blockchain like ether on ethereum, matic on polygon and bnb on BSC

Comment: If a contract called your method then the msg.sender will be the contract and not the address of the person who triggered the transaction

Comment: @MajdTL thank you for clarifying ! How do I get the value (amount) of the ERC20 token being sent to the contract ?

Comment: When someone transfer erc20 token then he should call transfer function in the erc20 contract, that function get the amount of tokens and the receiver as parameter

Comment: If u send erc20 tokens to ur contract then no function in your contract will be invoked (your contract will not notice or change anything in its state). The address of your contract will just be set as the new owner of the token and that happens inside the erc20 contract and not in ur contract

Comment: Later If your contract want to transfer its token, then it should have a function that can be triggered by you(owner) and that function should invoke then the transfer function in the erc20 token contract